# Errors scraping with Python - using requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have the following code:

```
def get_songs_link(link_of_artist):
    r = requests.get(link_of_artist).text
    sleep(randint(4,8))
    obj = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
    album={}
    for item in obj.select("#listAlbum > .album"):
        name = item.text
        songs = []
        for song in item.find_next_siblings('div', class_="listalbum-item"):
            if song.find_previous_sibling('div', class_='album') == item:
                songs.append([song.text, 'https://www.azlyrics.com/' + song.find('a')['href'][3:]])
        album[name] = songs
    return album

   list_link_artist_1 = ['https://www.azlyrics.com/f/floyda1bentley.html',
 'https://www.azlyrics.com/a/a.html',
 'https://www.azlyrics.com/s/snohaalegra.html',
 'https://www.azlyrics.com/a/aaliyah.html']

 #------------------

liz = []
for link in list_link_artisti_1):
    song_dict = get_songs_link(link)
liz.append(song_dict)
```

the list of link has len = 1000.

when I launch the script, after some times (it varies, the first time after 5 minutes, the second time after 10 minutes) it raises those errors:

```
 3%|▎         | 26/1000 [03:52<2:19:38,  8.60s/it]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 360, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 360, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, "Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato", None, 10060, None))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-103-290a8e4bc6a4>", line 2, in <module>
    song_dict = get_songs_link(link)
  File "<ipython-input-100-58ca37897386>", line 2, in get_songs_link
    r = requests.get(link_of_artist).text
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Marco\PycharmProjects\ortuproject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, "Impossibile stabilire la connessione. Risposta non corretta della parte connessa dopo l'intervallo di tempo oppure mancata risposta dall'host collegato", None, 10060, None))
```

what do you think it could be? I really have no Idea, I'm new to python and to web scraping like this, but we have to do an exam preparing a project with this stuff  . . .

thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Maybe you are sending too many request and your ip is getting blocked.

Comment: yes but I'm setting an honest sleep time, so it should not be a problem..should it?

Comment: _yes but I'm setting an honest sleep time_ Where? You should also consider using a `requests.Session` object.

Comment: @AMC     `sleep(randint(4,8))` after the request. If is incorrect please explain me.. and what is the difference between `request.session` and normal `request.get()` ?

Comment: @MarcoOnnis Ah right, I had missed it, I'm so used to seeing `time.sleep()`. _and what is the difference between request.session and normal request.get() ?_ https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects